# Plotting an exponential function in matlab

Tags: charts, matlab

I would like to develop some intuition for this language. Specifically about plotting functions on some interval. Here is a concrete example I am trying to work out. Plot exp(x) over the closed interval [-2,2]. Here exp(x) is Matlab notation for e^x, I think. This is the script based on a guide I just read :

x = [ -2 , 2 ];
y = exp(x);
plot(x,y)

The result is not an exponential curve, but a straight line. What is wrong with this script? And also, if anyone can recommend a good guide for this, I would appreciate it very much. Google results I found only have worked examples.

Comment: There is nothing wrong wit this script, but `x = [-2, 2]` will create an array of two data points. Whereas you want more data points, `x = -2:0.1:2` will create a vector of values between -2 and 2 with step size 0.1

Comment: try using `plot( x, y, 'o-' )` to see the points as well as the line which joins them to make rinkert's comment obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two methods of adjusting the number of points plotted (samples) of the function are to either specify the interval between the points or the number of points to be plotted. The `plot()` function will plot the vectors `x` and `y` which will plot the number of points equal to the length of vector `x`. Similar idea to an Excel sheet scatter plot that is joined with line.

### Setting the Interval Between the Plotting Points

[image: Interval Defined Plot]

```
X_Minimum = -2;
X_Maximum = 2;
Plotting_Interval = 0.25;

x = (X_Minimum: Plotting_Interval: X_Maximum);
y = exp(x); 

plot(x,y,'o-');
title(num2str(Plotting_Interval) + " Interval Between Points");
```

### Setting the Number of Plotting Points

[image: Number of Points Defined Plot]

```
X_Minimum = -2;
X_Maximum = 2;
Number_Of_Points = 18;

x = linspace(X_Minimum,X_Maximum,Number_Of_Points);
y = exp(x); 

plot(x,y,'o-');
title(num2str(Number_Of_Points) + " Points Plotted");
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Answer (score 0):

This is because you only input two point into the function plot():(-2,exp(-2)),(2,exp(2))
.In matlab,the x &y of plot(x,y) are vector of the points you have but not their intervals.